# Prevent a customer from checking out

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer

Is it possible to prevent a customer (under some circumstances) from checking out? I know it is possible to disable checkout from `System >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >> Checkout Options >> Disable Onepage Checkout`.

I want to know if there's a way to disable checkout for a particular customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

> *app/etc/module/Supravatm_DisableCheckout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Supravatm_DisableCheckout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout/>
            </depends>
        </Supravatm_DisableCheckout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> *app/code/local/DisableCheckout/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Supravatm_DisableCheckout>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Supravatm_DisableCheckout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
                <observers>
                    <Supravatm_DisableCheckout_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Supravatm_DisableCheckout_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>disableCheckoutButton</method>
                    </Supravatm_DisableCheckout_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/DisableCheckout/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Supravatm_DisableCheckout_Model_Observer {

    public function disableCheckoutButton(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        // Check if any customer is logged in or not
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

            //Load the customer's data
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            if($customer->getEmail() == 'specify customer email') {
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                //$quote->setHasError(true);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

> **Alternate Process:**

In your theme, edit the template file

> `checkout/onepage/link.phtml`

there is code

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif?>
```

**Alternative :**

You will find this function `isPossibleOnepageCheckout()` in

```
Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Link.php
```

You can extend this class and add your custom logic by which you can hide the checkout button.

Also in `/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

in `indexAction()`

write your condition so that user is redirected to cart page if condition is not fulfilled

Comment: Thanks. I changed `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index` to `controller_action_predispatch` to disable the checkout in every page, including direct access to `checkout/onepage`.

Comment: that is make sense